# Easy to use SNMP client library for c++?

Tags: c++, snmp

What's an easy to use SNMP client library for c++?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably the best choice is [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/).  Note that the library has "C" linkage but will work just fine with C++.

Answer (score 21):

SNMP++ is also a nice and open source library for C++ developers.

http://www.agentpp.com/api/cpp/snmp_pp.html

Comment: Easier to use than net-snmp in my opinion...

Comment: looks nice and simple. Is it really? is it robust and reliable?

Comment: Why not evaluate it? It's open source so you can feel free to try it out.

Comment: I will. But I'm on a tight schedule and I'd better not lose time with a poor library :) anyway it looks ok for now

Comment: AES 192 encryption failed for me using this library

Comment: There exists at least two different AES192 implementations: 
1. That one that was defined in a IETF draft. That has been originally implemented by SNMP++ (https://agentpp.com) and SNMP4J.
2. An implementation that was part of many Cisco devices which used a different algorithm than in the IETF draft. 
Most likely Antarus tested with a Cisco device. The second AES192 implementation is now also available in SNMP++ and SNMP4J.

Comment: Is there any Code example or some kind of "Get Started" tutorial available? All I can find is the class documentation over here: https://www.agentpp.com/doc/snmp++3.x/index.html

Answer (score 5):

I have found that Net-SNMP does not support multi-threading with v3 type queries.  So if you are writing an SNMP monitoring tool that will be polling multiple hosts then you will need to take this into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSNMP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opensnmp/) contains a complete multi-threaded implementation of SNMPv3 that is done in C++ (complete with classes, etc).  It's not heavily used and maintained though.

Net-SNMP with v3 over TLS/DTLS is likely to be threadsafe as it's really SNMPv3/USM that contains threading issues.  I think.